# pass array of arrays from routes to view node.js

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to pass an array of arrays from routes to view page. My data that I am trying to pass is :

```
[
    [10, 10],
    [20, 50],
    [30, 120],
    [40, 80],
    [50, 90],
    [60, 50],
    [70, 70],
    [80, 90],
    [90, 150],
    [100, 50],
    [110, 40],
    [120, 70],
    [130, 20],
    [140, 40],
    [200, 30]
]
```

I am getting it in below format:

```
["10,10,20,50,30,120,40,80,50,90,60,50,70,70,80,90,90,150,100,50,110,40,120,70,130,20,140,40,200,30"]
```

but I need it in the same format I am sending.
My index.js(routes file) is:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
var dataset = [
    [10, 10],
    [20, 50],
    [30, 120],
    [40, 80],
    [50, 90],
    [60, 50],
    [70, 70],
    [80, 90],
    [90, 150],
    [100, 50],
    [110, 40],
    [120, 70],
    [130, 20],
    [140, 40],
    [200, 30]
];
console.log(dataset);
res.render('index',{"data" : [dataset]});
});

module.exports = router;
```

and in my view file, I am trying to get it like:

```
<div class="hold_data" data-info={{data}}></div>
```

Please suggest if anyone knows how this can be achieved. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try adding it as a value to a key. That should work. Also, some code would be better to help you debug. Share your code.

Comment: @Bazinga777: added more info in the question. Please see now

Comment: `res.render('index',{"data" : dataset});` use this one .. see if this helps..

Comment: @Chandan : Initially used this one but same result

Comment: Please show us the template that this is supposed to go in.  If you want an array like this to go into your page as an array, then you have to put it in a `<script>` tag and turn the array into javascript source code (e.g. script text).

Comment: can you try this one - `res.render('index',{"data" : JSON.stringify(dataset)});` also provide where/how are you actually getting this data from server...?

Comment: @Chandan : this helped. Now I am getting it in the desired format. This is the dummy data m using currently .

Comment: great :)... let me write this as answer so we can have this question in accepted state...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `JSON.stringify` as below  -

```
 res.render('index',{"data" : JSON.stringify(dataset)});
```

Hope this helps.